# How to access the column name of table using while loop

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a below table(#Temp):

```
RowNo          Item
1              A
2              B
```

My requirement is if `Item` equals to `B` do action.

```
  declare @count int = 1
  WHILE(@count < (select count(*) from #Temp))
  Begin
  // Here I have to access my column name(Item) , so that I can check its value to B
  set @count = @count + 1
  End
```

Please suggest

Comment: What is the "action" you are going to do? Using a loop in TSQL is rarely the solution to look for but it might be depending on what action you are going to take.

Comment: Is something like `IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Temp WHERE Item = 'B' > 0)` a suitable test? This will tell you if you have any rows where `Item = 'B'`

Comment: @dash: No I can't do like that I have to use loop as there might be many rows related to Item: B and I have to pick the RowNumber in case of every match.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [DESCRIBE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/describe.html):

```
DESCRIBE my_table;
```

Or in newer versions you can use [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/columns-table.html):

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_database' AND TABLE_NAME = 'my_table';
```

Or you can use [SHOW COLUMNS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.html):

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM my_table;
```